# Attempted to load class "EmailBundle" from namespace "EmailBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, psr-4

I am using Symfony 5.3. I have 2 separate repositories I would like to use in my application.

composer.json file in my application looks like this.

```
"require": {
    "bundlezone/emailer": "dev-release/develop-setup",
    "bundlezone/tester": "dev-master"
}
```

And the composer file in `Emailer Repository` looks like this.

```
"autoload" : {
"psr-4" : {
  "BundleZone\\Emailer\\" : [""],
  "": ["Emailer"]
 }
},
```

And the composer file in `Tester Repository` looks like this.

```
"autoload" : {
"psr-4" : {
  "BundleZone\\Tester\\" : [""],
  "": ["Tester"]
 }
},
```

And `Emailer Repository` has multiple bundles. `EmailBundle.php` code looks like this.

```
<?php

namespace EmailBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class EmailBundle extends Bundle
{

}
```

And I added the class to the `config/bundles.php`.

```
 \EmailBundle\EmailBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

But, it still throws the below error.

> Attempted to load class "EmailBundle" from namespace "EmailBundle".
> Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Where do these files reside? Why do you have **two** namespaces in each of these package?  Why not use a **single** one that differs from package to package?

Comment: BundleZone is inside the vendor folder.

Comment: These 2 repositories are used in many projects. So some required functions are in one and the others and in the other.

Comment: Where is the file containing the `EmailBundle` class stored? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Your psr-4 entry strongly implies the bundles class name would be `BundleZone\Emailer\EmailBundle`.  I find it helps to look at the generated composer autoload files when tracking down these sorts of issues as well as looking at some of the existing bundles.